# C# Serilog how to log metrics?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, logging, serilog

I need help with serilog metrics, as if now I can log messages and log trace Id's as well, but how to log metrics using serilog, I was referring this package https://github.com/serilog-metrics/serilog-metrics but I feel this has been updated for a long time, could you please help with architecture & code.

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Trace()
                .CreateLogger();

using (logger.BeginTimedOperation("Time a thread sleep for 2 seconds."))
{
     Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The project serilog-metrics has no documentation, the code is very poor. You better don't think about.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Serilog Timings library instead. It's managed by the author of Serilog and has much better support and examples than Serilog-Metrics.
See: https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-timings